# Body is empty except when looking into "history"

Tags: wordpress, forms, smtp, contact-form-7

Whenever I send an email using a form all of the data get's added correctly however it's not showing up in the "main" email.

[Weird split up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UYF4.png)

Apparently the mail get's split in a main portion and an extra History portion which I need to explicitly click in order to open it.

Another issue I got is that it does send the email to certain emails but ignores certain others without any errors.

Main issue is the text not being shown properly though. Any Ideas?

P.S: sorry for image not showing everything don't want to spread around email addresses.

Another issue, mail only gets send when logged in as admin.

Mail tab
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcCg9.png)

Coding part:

```
<div class="form-group row mb-1">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Naam *</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">[text* your-name akismet:author class:form-

control]</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row mb-1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">E-mail *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">[email* your-email akismet:author_email class:form-control]</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row mb-1">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Onderwerp</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">[text your-subject class:form-control]</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row mb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Bericht</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">[textarea your-message class:form-control]</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">[submit class:btn class:btn-primary "Verzenden"]</div>
</div>
```

And I call the form using [contact-form-7 id="3348" title="Contact form NL"]

Comment: You need to provide more info before we can help you. What are you using to send email, is it a plugin, which one? You might be better of asking the plugin developers of support. If you coded your own form you will need us to show us the code of the form and of the send process.

Comment: Sure, I'm using WP Mail SMTP (which works when sending a test mail). See the main question for a screenshot of the mail tab + code.

Comment: Your setup looks fair enough (nothing special). Does this happen in every email client? A better screenshot of the email itself (with blurred content) might help a bit. Still I suspect the email itself is not the problem. Let this contact form sent a test email [here](https://www.mail-tester.com/). and check the plain text version.

Comment: There doesn't seem to arrive an email on that address... However there is a weird issue with the mail only being sent when the person filling in the form is logged in as an admin. Still the mail isnt arriving on the above.

Comment: Well this is starting to get broader. This goes beyond a programmer question. I suggest you search support, either contact WP Mail SMTP or contact a general WP support desk

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time anyway!